# asp.net textbox not updating form code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, delegates, updatepanel, code-behind

So I do want to update my TextBox called "ServerDataArea" in a thread running in code behind.

form:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox id="ServerDataArea" TextMode="multiline" Columns="50" Rows="15" runat="server" Enabled="false" />
        <br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="Message" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Button ID="SendMessage" runat="server" OnClick="appendMessage_Click" Text="Send" />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

This is how my code behind does to update this textbox:

```
public delegate void MyDelegate(string text);
private MyDelegate d;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
        d = new MyDelegate(MyMethod);
    }

    // create connection
    // ...

    // create thread
    if(Session["thread"] == null)
    {
        Session["thread"] = new Thread(new ThreadStart(RunReceiver));
    }

    Thread receiverThread = (Thread)Session["thread"];

    if (!receiverThread.IsAlive)
    {
        receiverThread.Start();
        Debug.WriteLine("Receiver thread started!");
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// receive messages from the server
/// </summary>
private void RunReceiver()
{
    byte[] data = null;

    while (con.GetClient().Connected)
    {
        // if stream contains data to recieve
        if (con.GetStream().DataAvailable)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("client receiving some data");

            // create new buffer to store received data
            data = new Byte[256];

            // read data from stream
            Int32 bytes = con.GetStream().Read(data, 0, data.Length);

            // convert to readable text
            responseData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, bytes);

            // display message in chat
            d(responseData);
        }

        Thread.Sleep(400);
    }
}

private void MyMethod(string text)
{
    ServerDataArea.Text += text + "\r\n";
}
```

the Debug.WriteLine(ServerDataArea.Text) does show me what should be visible in the textbox but it is not visible and I just can not figure out how to make it visible..

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: (Removed bunk) Your code is running on a seperate thread from the controls UI thread, and the UI will only allow updates via the controls UI thread.

Try updating the textbox value outside of the new thread you've created.

This is a difficult problem to solve so I suggest you achieve what you want a different way.

[Taken from here](http://bytes.com/topic/visual-basic-net/answers/372373-thread-textbox-question)
"Technically, you shouldn't be accessing a control from any other thread
except the one it was created on.

Accessing controls from a secondary thread is not guaranteed. It might work
sometimes but you shouldn't rely on it.

Instead, you should define a delegate and use the delegate to marshal the
calls from the secondary thread to the main thread when accessing your
controls. I'm not sure if this would speed up the update but here's how you
would update a textbox's text from another thread (VB alert):

**EDIT 2**: Converted vb function to C#

```
public delegate void SetTextDelegate(string sText);

private SetTextDelegate SetText = new SetTextDelegate(SetTextBoxText);

private void SetTextBoxText(string sText)
{
    tbStatus.Text = sText;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply and I replaced the Enabled="false" with ReadOnly="true" since Enabled = true by default but I am getting the same result, the textbox is still blank.

Comment: It was a bit of a stab in the dark to be honest, the real problem then is something to do with your threading, i.e. your code is running on a seperate thread from the UI thread, and the UI will only allow updates via the UI thread.

Comment: ok, so I updated the code behind showing you how I do when adding a delegate but I get same result so I must be doing something wrong there also?

Comment: @user2059696 Hmm it looks fine, are you sure the delegate is being setup correctly / when you want it in the Page_Load() ? As a test just instantiate it at a class scope, e.g. private MyDelegate d = new MyDelegate(MyMethod);

Comment: I can not because I get `A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property '_Default.MyMethod(string)` and if I make that method static I can not use the ServerDataArea.Text in that method because it is not static.

Comment: Ah ok, then just remove the if(!IsPostBack) statement, or does this work correctly? I guess it wouldn't because you are not changing it on a postback are you?